# Building a Call Recorder android app one react-native

Tags: react-native, call-recording

I am new to react-native and for my project, I need to add 'call recording' function in the app. I tried to find a package but couldn't find anything. So I want to know how difficult is it to build a 'call recorder' functionality from scratch or is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=react+native+call+recording+github
I didn't check any of those. I would start with the ones with more stars.

Comment: I have tried first two links but no success. I guess I have to write my own code for react-native as I have found some 'open source call recorder' (https://github.com/aykuttasil/CallRecorder) code for android so it needs to be converted to a module to be used in react-native. But I don't know how difficult and time consuming it it.

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/kevinresol/react-native-sound-recorder? It has 65 stars...

Comment: I haven't but as far as I have searched, call recording and sound recording are 2 different things. The only way I am able to think of is to use code of an open source android 'Call Recording' app and create a react-native module around it and then use it. But that need some native level understanding and will take some time also.

Comment: @Sumitsharma You found any good call recorder ? or you are developing your app in other language ? Please suggest me also what should I do ?

Comment: https://www.boldbeast.com/android/call_recorder.html
This is a good call recording app but if you read on their website, there are many issues with implementing a call recorder on you own because due to some regulation policy, google and apple doesn't promote call recording feature and it depends a lot on the hardware also.

Comment: thanks @Sumitsharma you cleared my doubts

Comment: I've one more question, not related to call recording, I'm new in react-native and I saw you are working in Kotlin instead of react-native. How you chose Kotlin in many different options like react-native, flutter, Kotlin/Java and many more.

Comment: I believe if you are developing basic functionalities and want both Android and IOS app then react-native or flutter is good but if you are planning to develop functionalities at core level then its better to go with native language.

Comment: @SumitJangra Did you able to create a native library for react-native using that call recorder

Comment: Nope @sahil555. I tried but it was not at top priority.